# org-mode: Getting logbook notes

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I figured out how to get entries I want using `org-agenda-get-day-entries` but that only returns the headline and its properties for each entry.  Is there any way to access the `LOGBOOK` of the corresponding entry and in particular any notes stored there?  I'd like to get the date each note was made as well so I can filter them.

The documentation on the elements API isn't great and I'm not sure I can even use it given a list of headlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse the drawer at point with `org-element-property-drawer-parser`:

```
(defun org-get-logbook-notes ()
  (save-excursion
    (unless (org-at-heading-p)
      (outline-previous-heading))
    (when (re-search-forward ":LOGBOOK:" (save-excursion
                                           (outline-next-heading)
                                           (point))
                             t)
      (let* ((elt (org-element-property-drawer-parser nil))
             (beg (org-element-property :contents-begin elt))
             (end (org-element-property :contents-end elt)))
        (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I found the org element API description inscrutible: https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html.  It just gives a list of element types with not much information and no actual APIs to access/parse the elements.  Is there a better reference somewhere?  I'm getting more comfortable with elisp and would like to do more advanced org information extraction.

Comment: I usually check the source code directly, or use the `helm-apropos` command to look for information. For example, `M-x find-library` `org` `RET` and from there I search with `helm-do-grep-ag`. In particular, see `org-element-map` and `org-map-entries`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great, but in the spirit of providing alternatives, the [org-ml](https://github.com/ndwarshuis/org-ml) project provides a functional API implemented over the org element API.

It contains a number of conveniences for working with org files, and is idiomatically similar to other modern Emacs packages like [dash](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), with which the user may already be familiar. In this case, using the `org-ml-headline-get-logbook-items` function might be preferable to finding and parsing the logbook by hand.

OTOH, it doesn't ship by default with Emacs, which may be a consideration.